# Trying to send a push notification when a user adds another user as a friend

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to set up a cloud function to send a notification to the receiving user but when I look at my logs it shows undefined for friendRequest.sender. What is the proper way to access nested json values in firebase cloud functions ?

```
exports.sendFriendRequestNotification = functions.database.ref('/friend_request/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {
 var friendRequestMessage = "Sent you a friend request";

 const friendRequest = event.data.current.val();
 console.log(friendRequest);

 const senderUid = event.data.current.child("sender").child("userId").val();
 const receiverUid = event.data.current.child("receiver").child("userId").val();

 console.log(senderUid); //getting null in fb logs


 const promises = [];

 if (senderUid == receiverUid) {    
    //if sender is receiver, don't send notification
    promises.push(event.data.current.ref.remove());             
    return Promise.all(promises);
 }

 const getInstanceIdPromise = admin.database().ref('/friend_request/{pushId}').once('value');
 const getReceiverUidPromise = admin.auth().getUser(receiverUid);

 return Promise.all([getInstanceIdPromise, getReceiverUidPromise]).then(results => {
     const instanceId = results[0].val();
     const receiver = results[1];
     console.log('notifying ' + receiverUid + ' about ' + friendRequestMessage + ' from ' + senderUid);

     const payload = {
         notification: {
             title: receiver.displayName,
             body: friendRequestMessage,
             icon: receiver.photoURL
            }
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
           console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
           console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });

});
```

});

My Friend Request Object

```
           { '-KyYOqdAJAi5tKv3rMIY': { receiver: 
  { soundCloudUserId: 0,
    userId: 'RvMaDClGqohUHrYDgKp9u5i03OI3  ',
    userName: 'fakefriend' },
 sender: 
  { soundCloudUserId: 0,
    userId: 'VqDgYnDMNVUtByH3uyLDNskPPlj1 ',
    userName: 'doug4less' },
 status: 'Pending' } }
```

Here is how the data looks in my Firebase DB

```
friend_request 
      -> VqDgYnDMNVUtByH3uyLDNskPPlj1 
          -> -KzPS5JjFE51hoqAP6_m
              -> receiver ...
                 sender   ...
                 status: "pending"
```

Here is how I am creating a the friend request

```
    public void addFriendRequest() {
    BrainBeatsUser sender = new BrainBeatsUser("VqDgYnDMNVUtByH3uyLDNskPPlj1 ", "doug4less");
    BrainBeatsUser receiver = new BrainBeatsUser("RvMaDClGqohUHrYDgKp9u5i03OI3  ", "fakefriend");

    DatabaseReference friendRequest = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("friend_request/" + mAddUser.getUserId());
    friendRequest
            .push()
            .setValue(new FriendRequest("Pending", sender, receiver))
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    friendUserDialog.dismiss();
                    Constants.buildInfoDialog(SocialActivity.this, "Request Sent", "Your friend request has been sent.");
                    sendFriendNotification();
                } else {
                    Constants.buildInfoDialog(SocialActivity.this, "Error", "There was an issue when sending that request.");
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 const senderUid = event.data.current.child("sender").child("userId").val();
 const receiverUid = event.data.current.child("receiver").child("userId").val();
```

event.data.current is a [DeltaSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot) object, you need to use syntax like this to get to its children.

Comment: I tried this and got null, I can see this has valid data in my real time database.

Comment: I just updated my answer, see how this works for you.

Comment: Still getting null :(.

Comment: Can you update your question with your latest code, and specify exactly where you are getting null?

Comment: I have updated the code, I am getting null in firebase console when trying to check the senderUid.

Comment: If you add this log statement, what does it return?  console.log(event.data.current.child("sender").val());

Comment: console logs shows value for friendRequest  and null for senderUid